# StylisticSet not working with unicode-math

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

Using LuaTeX, I want to activate the alternate glyphs for "g" and "1" that my (commercial) font offers via its Opentype features "Stylistic Set 2" and "Stylistic Set 11", respectively.

It does work for the main font (see 1st line of the below screenshot).

However, I want to get the same numbers and letters in the math font, especially the alternate forms for g and 1. It works for g, but not for 1 (see 4th line of the screenshot).

I tried to reconstruct this problem with some free font. Without success. I hope that someone can help me anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf}[
    Numbers = {Lining,Monospaced},
    StylisticSet={2,11}, 
]
\RequirePackage[math-style=upright,bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[Scale=MatchUppercase,StylisticSet={4,8}]
\setmathfont{TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf}[
    range = { up/{num,latin,Latin} },
    Numbers = {Lining,Monospaced},
    StylisticSet = {2,11}, 
]

\begin{document}
ijg, 0234567891\par
$ijg$, $0234567891$
\end{document}
```

The output of the above code are the 1st and 4th line of the following screenshot:

[image]

Part of my log file:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0, direction TLT
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0, direction TLT
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 527.9436fil, direction TLT
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 2.7
...\hbox(7.3+2.55)x345.0, glue set 243.26fil, direction TLT
....\localpar
.....\localinterlinepenalty=0
.....\localbrokenpenalty=0
.....\localleftbox=null
.....\localrightbox=null
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 i
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 j
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.18 plus 1.09 minus 0.72667
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 a
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 n
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 d
....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.18 plus 1.09 minus 0.72667
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.15
...\hbox(7.3+2.55)x345.0, glue set 244.31fil, direction TLT
....\localpar
.....\localinterlinepenalty=0
.....\localbrokenpenalty=0
.....\localleftbox=null
.....\localrightbox=null
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\mathon
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 i
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 j
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 g
....\mathoff
....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.18 plus 1.09 minus 0.72667
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 a
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 n
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 d
....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.18 plus 1.09 minus 0.72667
....\mathon
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 0
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 2
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 3
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 4
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 5
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 6
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 7
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 8
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 9
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(1)/m/n/10 1
....\mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue -2.55
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.25
..\hbox(6.75+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
...\hbox(6.75+0.0)x345.0, glue set 169.75fil, direction TLT
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\TU/TheSans_L-Math-5_Plain.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where (if anywhere) can I buy a copy of this font? Is it a true math font or just a font that happens to have some math symbols in it?

Comment: @mickep, it is a (as far as I know not for sale) variant of Lucas de Groot's TheSans. I think it does not contain any math symbols. I use it as a text font, but I also want to use its letters & numbers for the formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by defining

```
\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "onealt",
    type = "alternate",
    data = { ["one"] = "one.LinTab.alt1", }, }
}
```

and then replacing `StylisticSet={11}` by `RawFeature=+onealt,` in `\setmathfont`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your font but can demonstrate `StylisticSet` working to select `ss01` (Roundhand Script) in Stix Two Math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

$\symscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[StylisticSet={1}]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

$\symscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: actually looking at your question again you had sytlistic set working for some characters already so this is possibly not helpful, I may delete. could you add `\showoutput` to your preamble and show that part of the log?

Comment: Switching the g glyph in "math mode" works (stylistic set 2), but switching the 1 doesn't seem to work: although the shape changes slightly (I tried all stylistic sets from 1 to 20), it's not as desired. See the second screenshot I addded to my question. The goal is to make `$1$` look exactly like in text mode (first line).
I'm not sure which part you meant with "that part of the log". Is the one I added to my question okay? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Simon right part of the log:-) I'll look through it later, thanks

Comment: I've updated my screenshot in the question to show different combinations of `StylisticSet' (and that they all fail to create the correct shape for 1 in math mode).

Comment: I fixed the problem by defining
`\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
name = "onealt",
type = "alternate",
data = {
["one"] = "one.LinTab.alt1",
},
}
}` 
and using
`RawFeature=+onealt,`
in `\setmathfont`.

Comment: @Simon OK, do you want to post an answer as your comment may not be spotted so easily by future readers